# Xamarin.Forms Responsive Design

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I made app functionalities , and now need to make the design. I'm searching for some goot design patterns to be more responsive for multiple devices.How to make the Xamarin.forms componenets(Grid, Layout, Labels , buttons ,Stacks) be more responsive in the Views. Any suggestions about good articals, books, tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adaptive-ui-xamarin-forms/) you have a good article about designing in xamarin using an adaptative UI pattern. They are some basic tricks/tips that may help you to get a better multi-device design experience.

Hope it helps you as it helped me in the past! ^^

Comment: Hey, I know your reply is old, but that article is even older, and it use Code behind for adaptiveness, is there anything in XAML to make it adaptive